# Creating Multiple folders with mkdir() Function using loop c++

Tags: c++, mkdir

I want to create folders in a directory by naming them in a sequence like `myfolder1`, `myfolder2`. i tried doing it with `mkdir()` function using a `for loop` but it doesn't take 'integer variables' and only takes 'const char values'. what to do now? is there any other function which do that or can `mkdir()` do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any library calls that take an integer like you are asking.  What you need to do is embed the number into the string before passing it to mkdir().  Since you tagged this question with 'c++' I've demonstrated a C++ oriented way of accomplishing this below.

```
#include <sstream>  // for std::ostringstream
#include <string>   // for std::string

const std::string baseFolderName = "myfolder";
for (int i = 1; i < 20; ++i)
{
    std::ostringstream folderName;
    folderName << baseFolderName << i;
    mode_t mode = 0; //TBD: whatever is appropriate
    mkdir(folderName.str().c_str(), mode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much It did the work! :) and i put some conditional statements too to insert the dates i wanted in the folder names.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this, you can use `itoa(...)`

Lets say

```
i = 20;
char buffer [33];
itoa (i,buffer,10);    //10 means decimal
```

Now `buffer = "20\0"`

After this conversion you can add `buffer` to your default string.

So, all in all, you can use:

```
std::string str = "string";
char buffer[33] ;
itoa(20, buffer, 10);
str.append(buffer);
mkdir(str.c_str());
```

Comment: But then it would be a string, i want to use it in for loop like if your method is correct i would e able to write   
    for (buffer = 0; buffer<21; buffer++)
    {
    mkdir("buffer");
}

correct?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you really want to, but it is possible to write for loop to create some directories.